# Error when trying to run apps installed as snap packages - Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, snap

After installing a snap package I have an error when I try to run the app.

For example:

```
sudo snap install ubuntu-clock-app
/snap/bin/ubuntu-clock-app
failed to create user data directory. errmsg: Permission denied
```

The same occur with other apps.

I have my HOME directory encrypted. I suspect this is related to the problem.

Comment: it looks like snap doesn't work with encrypted $HOME. See this https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1592696

Comment: So is a bug! I'm going to wait for a fix.

Comment: I guess it's a new bug because as I remember I was able to install and try some snap packages (notes and nmap) a month or two ago and now I can't open them.

Comment: Something similar happening without an encrypted home folder, command line program says "permision denied."

Answer (score -1):

I also have an encrypted home, and it works just fine. The user data directory is defined as `$HOME/snap/<snapname>/<snapversion>`. It's created when the application is run. However, if one runs an application as `sudo` one can end up with `$HOME/snap` owned by root, in which case a subsequent run without sudo will result in a permission denied trying to create a directory within a directory owned by root.

Make sure `$HOME/snap` isn't owned by root (chown if necessary).

Comment: Didn't work. Looks like it's a bug.